# Convolutional neural net testing accuracy stays constant after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I see improving training accuracies after each iteration, but testing accuracy stays fixed at exactly 0.7545 after each epoch. I understand hitting a ceiling on accuracy at some point but don't understand why I don't at least see slight variations in accuracies (up or down). I'm training on about 800 images total.

Things I've tried:
- Switch to SGD optimizer.
- Start with learning rate of 0.01 and reduce until 0.00000001.
- Remove regularization layers.

```
#PARAMS
dropout_prob = 0.2
activation_function = 'relu'
loss_function = 'categorical_crossentropy'
verbose_level = 1
convolutional_batches = 32
convolutional_epochs = 10
inp_shape = X_train.shape[1:]
num_classes = 3
opt = SGD(lr=0.00001)
opt2 = 'adam'


def train_convolutional_neural():
    y_train_cat = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 3) 
    y_test_cat = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 3)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=inp_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_prob))
    model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(Dense(64,activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_prob))
    model.add(Dense(32,activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_cat, batch_size=convolutional_batches, epochs = convolutional_epochs, verbose = verbose_level, validation_data=(X_test, y_test_cat))
    model.save('./models/convolutional_model.h5')
```

Comment: From my quick look at this I read your code as testing 10 times (epochs) using 32 sample records (batch_size). So your "coverage" of the data is only 320 records out of 800. I think this is the reason your model does not improve, you are simply not feeding the network with enough values.

Comment: @TimSeed convolutional_batches refers to batch size, meaning the number of observations that go in each batch. if there are 800 observations then 800/32 = 25 which is how many batches are trained in each epoch.

Comment: What's the ratio of each of the 3 classes in `y_test`? It seems quite likely that your model is predicting the same class for all testing set instances. You can try to print out the predicted values for `X_test`, and see if that's the case.

Comment: Also, did you normalize both `X_train` and `X_test` before feeding them into the net? If your model is indeed predicting the same class for all instances, that might be one of the possible reasons.